# Rails 3 Including multiple tables in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im working on a rails application for tournaments. I have three models im working with on this query:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tournaments

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament_type
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  has_many :player_matches, :dependent => :destroy

class PlayerMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player_one, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => "player_one"
  belongs_to :player_two, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => "player_two"
```

In the show action of the tournaments_controller, im calling the following query:

```
Tournament.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:player_matches, :players).first()
```

While the tournaments and player_matches are done in a single join, the players are queried individually, since my code depends on them:

```
Player Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `players`.*, t0.tournament_id as the_parent_record_id FROM `players` INNER JOIN `players_tournaments` t0 ON `players`.id = t0.player_id WHERE (t0.tournament_id = 14)
Player Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
Player Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `players`.* FROM `players` WHERE `players`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
```

How can i change this up, so that it is all pulled in one query?

Comment: Tossing this out as a comment since something similar fixed my N+1 problem, but I'm not sure if it'll work for you. What do you get if you change your `includes` call to `includes(:player_matches => :players)`?

Comment: Also, tossing this out... make sure you're looking the SQL used in production mode, not development.

Comment: Have yet to run this in production mode. That output is from the server console in terminal, as supposed to the logs, so i know i have the correct output :).

Comment: I replicated the exact setup you have with Rails 3.0.3 and don't get the same output. The first 'Player Load' line is the one that loads all the players at once, and it's the only one I get.  Is your output really from executing just that one line of code?  My guess is that you're looping through players in your view. I would shut your server down, open Rails console, and execute that one line while watching the SQL in development.log.

Comment: Yes, i have a collection that's passed to a partial. That partial then loops through it.

Comment: I think what the partial is doing may be causing extra player loads. For example, the way you're loading tournaments, calling tournament.players would not cause more loading, but calling player_one or player_two on the tournament's player matches would.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```ruby
Tournament.where(:id => params[:id]).includes([{:player_matches => :player_one}, :players]).first()
```

That should do the trick. And really, the combination of array notation and hash notation is a bit messy to get sorted at first, but work with the console and you'll find out which syntax doesn't crash :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting multiple player queries coming back though :(. I wonder if maybe my problem lies with how I am using the data, or how i have the db structured.